# Jira with plugins in 1 docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, jira, docker-image

I'm looking for a way to run jira inside a docker container and ship (start) all needed plugins with it. My Jira gets restarted quite often so I don't want to install all plugins manually over and over again.

Also I would like to avoid using some kind of pipeline after jira is started. As far a I know, Jira plugins can be installed using some Rest API. But I would like to avoid http requests for this.

Is there a way to have a custom image where I can include my plugins? This is the base image: https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/jira-software

Storing the actual plugin files (downloadable from marketplace) in e.g. an artifactory is not a problem.

Looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

We use docker-compose to include our plugin in Jira for testing purposes.
You have to map volume from your local plugin file, to Jira's plugins directory, so when it starts, it will automatically pick up your plugin.
It looks more or less like this:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  jira:
    image: atlassian/jira-software:latest
    restart: "no"
    volumes:
      - ./plugins/plugin.jar:/opt/atlassian/jira/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/atlassian-bundled-plugins/plugin.jar
```

You can also easily build your own image, cloning their repo and modifying Dockerfile to copy your plugin in Jira's folder.
e.g.

```
COPY my-plugin.jar
RUN cp /my-plugin.jar ${JIRA_INSTALL_DIR}/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/atlassian-bundled-plugins/my-plugin.jar
```

Comment: I was surprised, but this works (tested with Jira Server 8.2.4)! It appears in system apps. I still haven't figured how to load a license for the plugin yet. Any idea?

Comment: @merlosy We use sql scripts for applying Jira license, but plugin license is set during tests. Probably you could do the same using sql scripts, but licenses for plugins are kept in different tables than Jira.