# How can I run jira in dev mode as a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

So we have a jira plugin under development that needs be manually tested on various jira versions. Using `atlas-debug` for this is a ***PAIN*** and I'd much rather be able to pull down a docker image, do my testing on it, then discard the container again.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62992519/jira-with-plugins-in-1-docker-image), my approach is

`start_jira.sh`

```
echo "Reading versions..."

JIRA_VERSION=${1:-latest}
echo -e "\tJira:   $JIRA_VERSION"

PLUGIN_VERSION=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)
echo -e "\tPlugin: $PLUGIN_VERSION"

PLUGIN_FILE="./target/my_plugin-$PLUGIN_VERSION.jar"

if [[ -f "$PLUGIN_FILE" ]]; then
    echo "Starting ..."
  else
    echo "'$PLUGIN_FILE' does not exist. Have you run mvn install?"
    exit 1
fi

touch .env
echo "JIRA_VERSION=$JIRA_VERSION" > .env
echo "PLUGIN_FILE=$PLUGIN_FILE" >> .env

docker-compose up -d
```

where

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  jira:
    image: atlassian/jira-software:${JIRA_VERSION}
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ${PLUGIN_FILE}:/opt/atlassian/jira/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/atlassian-bundled-plugins/plugin.jar
```

That seems to start fine.
However, jira asks for a license.

I think it's neither reasonable nor advisable to ask developers to generate trial licenses left and right just so they can test on a certain jira instance.

Is there any way I can run this jira image in something akin to dev mode where it will work but expire in a couple days or something?

Answer (score 2):

You need atlassian sdk docker. There is no official sdk image from atlassian. You can create your own or to search the web for the 3rd party images. e.g https://hub.docker.com/r/codeclou/docker-atlassian-sdk

Comment: Hm ... I can't get these images to run, I guess they're too old. Will have to do it ourselves.